# Align a bootstrap-growl alert bottom left

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-notify

According to the [bootstrap-growl options documentation](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/#growl-documentation-options) we can use `placement` options to stick the growl notifications elsewhere. I'm trying to put my growl notifications **bottom left**, but it's not working.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.growl({
        message: 'Test.'
    }, {
        placement: {
            from: "bottom",
            align: "left"
        },
        delay: 1000000
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-growl/1.0.6/bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
```

The options *are* being parsed it seems: the `delay` option is honored. So are others if I add them. However, the placement remains at its default top/right position.

I'm using bootstrap-growl version 1.0.6. Version 2 seems to be in the making but not released yet. Perhaps part of my problem is that the bootstrap-growl website's documentation is aimed at V2?

What am I missing here? Probably something obvious...

Comment: Please do not use the file found on cdnjs 1.0.6 this is a mix between my plugin and another.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Oh wew, that's confusing! Did you contact the folk from CDNJS about that yet? In any case, could you suggest an edit to the question with a better link, that still reproduces the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I know it is confusing if you check out my [github](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-growl#thinking-of-a-rename) page you'll notice I am renaming my plugin to help resolve this problem. I sent them a message today, because I hadn't noticed this was in issue until recently.

Comment: The worst thing is I am not sure what they are going to do about it though. If they just pull my version out it will break any ones site who is using it. I would really hate to break people's site because of a very understandable confusion. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position` instead, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.growl({
        message: 'Test.'
    }, {
        position: {
            from: "bottom",
            align: "left"
        },
        delay: 1000000
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-growl/1.0.6/bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
```

If you check the [1.0.6 release's options documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-growl/tree/1.0.6#options) you'll see that the relevant option is not (yet) called "`placement`" but (still) called "`position`". Some other options seem to be different too.

Comment: Tyvm, that was it! With your help I found the answer on GitHub too, I've added a link and bit of text to the answer.

Comment: I was looking for references in the doc, but you won. Thanks!